# In JMeter getting error while generating request payload data dynamically with Groovy

Tags: dynamic, request, jmeter

This is the request JSON

```
{
    "Transaction": {
        "TrType": "Vehicle",  
        "CustomerType": "${__chooseRandom(Individual,Company,)}", 
    },
    "IndividualClient": {
        "firstName": "test first name",
        "lastName": "test last name"
    }
    "CompanyClient": {
        "CompanyName": "test company name",
    }
}
```

So if customer type = Individual then generate Individual else generate Company.

I used JSR223 Pre-Processor and in that.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def jsonRequest = null

JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
jsonRequest = jsonSlurper.parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

println(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonRequest)))

if (jsonRequest.Transaction.CustomerType.equalsIgnoreCase("Individual")) {

    jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
    jsonBuilder.IndividualClient {
        firstName "test first name"
        lastName "test last name"
    }
    vars.put("customertypedetails",jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
    println(vars.get("customertypedetails"))
} else {
    jsonBuilder2 = new JsonBuilder()
    jsonBuilder2.CompanyClient {
        companyName "test company name"
    }
    vars.put("customertypedetails",jsonBuilder2.toPrettyString())
    println(vars.get("customertypedetails"))
}
```

reference link I used for this purpose.
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/jvm-languages/groovy/groovy-json-example/

This ${customertypedetails} i am using in my JSON as;

```
{
      "Transaction": {
        "TrType": "Vehicle",  
        "CustomerType": "${__chooseRandom(Individual,Company,)}", 
      },
      ${customertypedetails}
}
```

But i am getting exception

> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}'
>   or ',' but got current char '$' with an int value of 36
>
> The current character read is '$' with an int value of 36 expecting
>   '}' or ',' but got current char '$' with an int value of 36 line
>   number 32 index number 907   $customertypedetails, ..^ at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]

When I printed (vars.get("customertypedetails") I am getting

```
{
    "IndividualClient": {
        "firstName": "test first name",
        "lastName": "test last name"
    }
}
```

instead of

```
"IndividualClient": 
 {
     "firstName": "test first name",
     "lastName": "test last name"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) you will have a valid JSON, i.e. starting with `{` and ending with `}`.

If for some reason this is something you don't want you can remove starting and trailing curly braces like:

```
def ctd = vars.get('customertypedetails')
ctd = ctd.substring(ctd.indexOf('{') +1,ctd.lastIndexOf('}'))
vars.put('customertypedetails',ctd)
```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; with the provided solution Starting with { and ending with } removed first issue still present.

Comment: {
      "Transaction": {
        "TrType": "Vehicle",  
        "CustomerType": "${__chooseRandom(Individual,Company,)}", 
      },
      ${customertypedetails} // this is giving error
}

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char '$' with an int value of 36

The current character read is '$' with an int value of 36 expecting '}' or ',' but got current char '$' with an int value of 36 line number 32 index number 907 $customertypedetails, ..^ at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]

Comment: index number 305
  ${newcustomertypedetails}
..^
 at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.complain(JsonParserCharArray.java:153) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
 at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeJsonObject(JsonParserCharArray.java:144) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
 at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValueInternal(JsonParserCharArray.java:186) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
 at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValue(JsonParserCharArray.java:157) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
 at

Comment: Please any one provide the solution or tell me what i am doing incorrect